# How to draw the following specific Venn diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I wish to draw the following Venn diagram as ilustrated below:
[image: Ilustration]

I already managed to do the following code, remains to draw the set $I = J \cap X \cap Y$ and to put the the letter J down, according to the Figure:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) circle (1) (0,1)  node [text=black,above] {$X$}
  (1,0) circle (1) (1,1)  node [text=black,above] {$Y$}
  (-0.4, -0.3) rectangle (1.5,0.5) node [text=black,above] {$J$}
 (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2) node [text=black,above] {$S$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `save path`/`use path` directives to avoid repeating code.
I took the liberty of rewriting part of your code.

The filled part is put on the background layer for it not to eat a part of the set borders.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[save path = \circleX] (0,0) circle (1);
        \node[above] at (0,1) {$X$};
        \draw[save path = \circleY] (1,0) circle (1);
        \node[above] at (1,1) {$Y$};
        \draw[save path = \rectangleJ] (-0.4, -0.3) rectangle (1.5,0.5)
            node [below right] {$J$};
        \draw (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2)
            node [above] {$S$};
    
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \clip[use path = \circleX];
            \clip[use path = \circleY];
            \clip[use path = \rectangleJ];
            
            \fill[use path = \rectangleJ, blue];
        \end{scope}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

**EDIT**

A way to get the `J` node at the bottom would be to do, instead of the `\draw` defining the rectangle:

```
\draw[save path = \rectangleJ] (-0.4, -0.3) coordinate (A)
                                    rectangle (1.5,0.5) coordinate (B);
\coordinate (C) at (A -| B);
\node[below] at (C) {$J$};
```

**EDIT 2**

To add the name of the filled area, a possibility is to add `node[pos = .5] {$I$}` at the end of the `\draw` command defining the rectangle.
Indeed, in this case, the intersection is more or less at the center of the rectangle.

Comment: You have any sugestion for to insert the $I$ inside of the set blue that you do?

Comment: @FranciscoAntonio Please see my second edit. For readability, maybe the `blue` I used to fill is not the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2) node[above] {$S$};
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1] (0,1) node[above left] {$X$};
\draw (1,0) circle[radius=1] (1,1) node[above right] {$Y$};
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\clip (1,0) circle[radius=1];
\fill[blue] (-0.4, 0.5) rectangle (1.5,-0.3) node[black,pos=0.5]{I};
\end{scope}
\draw (-0.4, 0.5) rectangle (1.5,-0.3) node[below] {$J$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Venn diagram with blue center]